# reading data from Kafka and storing it in dynamo db

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I need to read data from multiple topics in Kafka broker and store the data in Dynamo DB.
Any reference code or any specific method i can go ahead with.

I Tried using https://github.com/shikhar/kafka-connect-dynamodb but i couldn't get much help as am new to this.

Comment: It is not easy to get started with Kafka. There is very limited documentation and tutorials. The majority of the documentation and tutorials is inadequate and deprecated. I suggest you explorer Kafka with an trial-and-error approach starting with the basic stuff and creating a consumer. I highly suggest you to start with Spring-Kafka, it creates an abstraction-layer for Kafka which makes it easier to get started. Separate your task into three sub-tasks. Consume from multiple topics, connect to Dynamo DB, and push data to Dynamo DB. Create stackoverflow questions as you learn and need help.

Comment: Checkout https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/ for reliable Spring-Kafka documentation. I suggest you to use https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev for your local development environment when learning.  Unfortunately I do not know of any great beginner guides for Kafka.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is about recommending books or tutorials. According SO policies this in inappropriate content. However I believe we can share with you some links in comments. Yes, start with Spring Kafka:  https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka. Then scroll down to the end of it reference manual and find a good addition like `Spring Integration for Apache Kafka` to learn what is EIP Channel Adapters and Gateway. For writing to DynamoDB you can also use the mentioned Spring Integration and wrap the call into the Service Activator: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn

Comment: What exactly did you do to try using that Connect library?

Comment: @kkflf BTW, The Apache Kafka documentation (and parts of the Confluent ones) is open-source, if you feel it can be improved. Not sure which parts you think are deprecated

Comment: I appreciate the great work done by all the contributors of Kafka. I am referring to the cwiki for Kafka and the limited amount of tutorials around the internet - Not specifically provided by the Kafka team(s). I have not found any deprecated documentation on https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/ - But I think this documentation is inadequate for newcomers. I think the documentation is intermediate level - not well suited for beginners whom try to learn the basic nor the people who want to learn the implementation details of Kafka. Mailing-list + trail-and-error worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options to read from Kafka and write to Dynamo is Nifi.

Use ConsumeKafka Nifi Processor as consumer:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-0-9-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka/

and PutDynamoDB to write:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.dynamodb.PutDynamoDB/

This also facilitates to do any quick transformation, forking etc.

[image: This is how i implemeted]